# Button change state when scrolling and resuming

Tags: android, scroll, android-button

I have a `ListView`, some `View` in this list have a `Button` (not every views have). This button have 2 states : START and STOP. So whenever I scroll the list, or turn on another app, then get back on this app (not close permanently), the button's state changed back to its previous state. Is there anyway to fix it ?

It works fine. The problem is the state is not saved, so when I scroll, it call `getView` again, and the state change back to the previous state. And when change app then get back too

---

This is the `getView` function, where all the problem start :

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ContentViewHolder.CaptionTitleHolder captionHolder = null;
        ContentViewHolder.PreCookingViewHolder preCookingHolder = null;
        ContentViewHolder.CookingViewHolder cookingHolder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (type == CAPTION_TITLE){
            if (convertView == null){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.caption_title_view, parent, false);
                captionHolder = new ContentViewHolder.CaptionTitleHolder();
                captionHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.caption_title_textview);
                convertView.setTag(captionHolder);
            } else {
                captionHolder = (ContentViewHolder.CaptionTitleHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            captionHolder.text.setText(((RecipeContentActivity2.CaptionTitle) allItems.get(position)).getContent());

        } else if (type == COOKING){
            if (convertView == null){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cooking_steps_and_timer, parent, false);
                cookingHolder = new ContentViewHolder.CookingViewHolder();
                cookingHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cooking_step_content);
                cookingHolder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cooking_timer);
                cookingHolder.skipButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_skip);
                cookingHolder.startButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_timer);

                convertView.setTag(cookingHolder);
            } else {
                cookingHolder = (ContentViewHolder.CookingViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            CookingStep myStep = (CookingStep) allItems.get(position);
            setUpCookingView(convertView, cookingHolder, myStep);
        } else {
            if (convertView == null){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pre_cooking_view, parent, false);
                preCookingHolder = new ContentViewHolder.PreCookingViewHolder();
                preCookingHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pre_cooking_textview);
                convertView.setTag(preCookingHolder);
            } else {
                preCookingHolder = (ContentViewHolder.PreCookingViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            preCookingHolder.text.setText((String) allItems.get(position));
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private void setUpCookingView(final View c, final ContentViewHolder.CookingViewHolder view, final CookingStep step){
        String stepOrder = context.getResources().getString(R.string.step_order) + " " + step.getOrder();
        String content = "<b>" + stepOrder + ":</b> " + step.getContent() + "\n";
        view.text.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));

        if (step.getMinute() != null && step.getMinute() > 0){
            if (step.getMyTimer() == null) {
                CookingTimer2 timer = new CookingTimer2(step.getMinute()) {

                    @Override
                    public void upgradeUI() {
                        view.time.setText(toString());
                    }
                };
                step.setTimer(timer);
            }
            view.time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.startButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.skipButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



            view.startButton.setText(R.string.button_available);
            view.skipButton.setText(R.string.skip_button_content);
            view.startButton.setEnabled(step.isTurnEnable());
            view.skipButton.setEnabled(step.isTurnEnable());
            view.time.setText(step.getMyTimer().toString());


            view.startButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        if (!view.startButton.isPressed()) {
                            view.startButton.setPressed(true);
                            view.startButton.setText(R.string.button_pressed);
                            step.getMyTimer().doStart();
                            //c.setTag(R.id.button_timer, true);
                        } else {
                            view.startButton.setPressed(false);
                            view.startButton.setText(R.string.button_available);
                            step.getMyTimer().doStop();
                            //c.setTag(R.id.button_timer, false);
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            view.skipButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        step.getMyTimer().doStop();
                        ((RecipeContentActivity2) context).enableNextStep();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } else {
            view.time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.startButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.skipButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
```

---

Somehow I managed to fix the problem in case when scrolling using this the timer's state. Thanks  milosmns for reminding me that I still have my timer ticking

```
if (step.getMyTimer().isTicking()){
                view.startButton.setPressed(true);
                view.startButton.setText(R.string.button_pressed);
            }
```

But I still have that problem when switch to another app, then get back. It seems that in this case, the `getView` didn't get called. So what should I do next ?

---

So yeah I've found a hackish way to do this. I don't really like it though

In my activity :

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (wasStoped)
            ((MyAdapter)listContent.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        wasStoped = true;
        super.onStop();
    }
```

I still want to know any other method

Comment: Please add more info. Your problem is that you have a button which isn't clickable when transitioning or scrolling?

Comment: It works fine. The problem is the state is not saved, so when I scroll, it called `getView` again, and the state change back to the previous state. And when change app then get back too

Comment: Oh, have you tried persisting button state on your adapter data? For example, if you have a list in your adapter (`List<MyData> mData = new ArrayList<>();`), add one more field to the `MyData` class, something like `mButtonState`, and then in your `getView()` check that value, i.e. `mData.get(position).getButtonState()` and update the button.

Comment: I did think of it that way, but I don't want to get my data class involve with the View, that's why I'm stuck here. I prefer to keep my classes pure OOP

Comment: share your adapter code it will be easy to help u actually you have to maintain some value in dataset which can solve your issue

Comment: I just post `getView` of my `Adapter`

Comment: @NguyenQuangAnh Ok, makes sense if you want to keep your UI code apart from the data code. Actually, if your button has 2 states, that must mean that your data has 2 states as well, but you may not be seeing it - i.e. if you have a timer which colors your button red when done, timer being alive is 1 state, and timer being finished/dead is the other state. Something like that.

Comment: @NguyenQuangAnh But since timers are tricky to maintain, and listeners are bound to recycled ViewHolders, maybe you need to work on another approach. This may complicate things in the future and make things more difficult to maintain. I would advise to keep track of timers outside of the adapter, and update the data via some kind of custom-made event, then for your adapter do `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the UI thread.

Comment: Yes I use another class to manage the timer, inside the adapter is just starting or stopping the timer via button click. And what do you mean by `listeners are bound to recycled ViewHolders` ? Should I check whether the buttons have the listener attached to them each times I set a listener ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to resolve this, by implement for myself my Button, with custom state. Yeah I just realize that depend on button's state `pressed` is not the way, since there are too many interference that can change this state.

```
public class TimerButtonControl extends Button{
    private static final int[] STATE_RUN = {R.attr.timer_run};

    private boolean running = false;

    public TimerButtonControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setRun(boolean r){
        running = r;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }
    public boolean isRunning() {return running; }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState =  super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (running) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_RUN);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }
}
```

and then define xml for this button :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/clock_button_not_pressed"
        app:timer_run="false" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/clock_button_pressed"
        app:timer_run="true" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_unavailable"
        android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

then use it inside my layout :

```
<com.username.mypackage.uiassistance.TimerButtonControl
        android:id="@+id/button_timer"
        android:padding="4dip"
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cooking_step_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/timer_button"
        android:enabled="false"/>
```

and finally inside adapter :

```
if (step.getMyTimer().isTicking()){
                view.startButton.setRun(true);
                view.startButton.setText(R.string.button_pressed);
            }

            view.startButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        if (!view.startButton.isRunning()) {
                            view.startButton.setRun(true);
                            view.startButton.setText(R.string.button_pressed);
                            step.getMyTimer().doStart();
                        } else {
                            view.startButton.setRun(false);
                            view.startButton.setText(R.string.button_available);
                            step.getMyTimer().doStop();
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Hope it could help anybody else that have the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0):

use holder class like:

```
public View getView(final int i, View view, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View vi = view;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row_cart, null);
            holder.yourbutton = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btn);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
            holder.yourbutton.setText("Start");
     }
     class ViewHolder {
           Button yourbutton
    }
```

Comment: ViewHolder can't solve this problem. I'm using ViewHolder.

Comment: hmm..when you changing state of  button store it in database or sheared preference then when you get view set that value on button.

Answer (score 0):

Your onCreate method is most likely being called again in order to rebuild the view and is refreshing the state of the button, you need to save the state of the button.

You can do this using the sharedPreferences.

You can view the documentation on how to implement this
[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: I think the problem lie in `getView` of `Adapter` when scrolling, and `onResume` when switch to another app then get back. I do know that I have to store the necessary data somewhere, but I don't know how.

Comment: I did just now. I didn't do anything in `onResume` or any other function, except `onCreate`, and the code is inside the Adapter

Comment: I just read about `SharedPreferences`. It seems that this method will save the data to some local file, and it's still there even if you quit the app. Is there anything that make the data exist only until the app is closed permanently ? for example `setTag` to the View. But then when I debug it, I noticed that not always the same View object is used (by comparing its address). Sometimes when I switch to another app, then get back, it used another View object.